# Saving an iCloud Drive security scoped URL on iOS (UIDocumentPickerViewController)

Tags: ios, cocoa, icloud

I'm trying to save the security scoped URL returned from iCloud document picker (UIDocumentPickerViewController)

The documentation states:

> If the URL is not a ubiquitous URL, save a bookmark to the file using
>   the
>   bookmarkDataWithOptions:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error:
>   method and passing in the NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
>   option. Calling this method creates a bookmark containing a
>   security-scoped URL that you can use to open the file without further
>   user intervention.

However, the compiler says that NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope is not supported on iOS.

Anyone know what's going on here....?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Just wondering if you have found solution to the problem?

Comment: Still 'negotiating' with Apple DTS :-(

Comment: On the documentation this is the link:https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html is clearly says this is what you need to do to save a bookmark for secure scoped URL. This is perplexing.

Answer (score 8):

After further digging, it turns out option `NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope` is NOT needed at all when creating bookmark data in IOS. It's an option for OS X. You can just pass nil for the option field. I think Apple's document is confusing at the best.
However, you do need to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` before creating the bookmark and make sure the call returns 1 (success) before proceed. Otherwise, bookmark creation will fail. Here is the sample code:

```
 if ([url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource]==1) {  
     NSError *error;  
     NSData *bookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:nil  
                      includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil  
                                       relativeToURL:nil  
                                               error:&error];  
     if (error) {
        //handle error condition  
     } else {
        // save your bookmark  
     }
 }  
 [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
```

Again Apple's document is confusion at the best! It took me a lot of time to find out this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today, and indeed the compiler says `NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope` is not available on iOS.

But to my surprise, if I use the raw constant instead (`NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope` maps to `( 1 << 11 )`, the method seems to work. It returns a valid bookmark data object, and when I call `[[NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeToURL:bookmarkDataIsStale:stale]`, a valid security-scoped `NSURL` is returned and I can access the files and directories. Also, I tested these with iCloud Drive. And the documentation only says this should work for third-party document providers.

I am not sure how reliable this approach is, because it seems that Apple engineers didn't have time to finish up this feature, so disabled it in the last minute. Or it could be simply a bug in the header file. If anyone finds out more about this, please comment.

Comment: Tried with a third-party extension: Box. Unfortunately with the raw constant, the returned bookmark data is null. Other cloud providers like Dropbox and Google Drive don't support the open mode at this moment, so they can't be tested.

Comment: Box's open mode may not be working properly. At least not with file packages. I tried to list the file package contents, but get nothing. This same method works fine with iCloud Drive, so it seems that although Box "supports" the open mode, it isn't working properly.